# Cannot map through array of files/images React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, file, input

I am creating an image(s) upload component in React. Every time the file input field changes I am updating the `images` state. Below the input field I am trying to loop through the images and log their names in the console. However, as soon as I select an image, I get the error `TypeError: images.map is not a function.`
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ImagesInput = (props) => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    const imageInputChange = (e) => {
        setImages(e.target.files)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input {...props} type="file" onChange={imageInputChange} multiple />
            {images.map((image) => {
                console.log(image)
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ImagesInput;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of e.target.files is an array-like not an actual array. Just convert it to array before passing to **setImages**, like

```
setImages([...e.target.files])
```

[Read here about array-like](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md#array-likes)

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
setImages(e.target.files)
```

Try to add a condition like this, make sure e.target.files is the image arr you want

```
if(e.target.files){
  setImages(e.target.files)
}
```