# Why I'm getting the error array from getters is not a function Vuex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter, vuex

After filling the inputs with arrival point and departure point and afterwords filtering the flights with selects I'm getting the error this.flights.filter is not a function, even though flights comes from getters and is a type of an array. Am I missing something ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hrqfyc?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FSearchBtn.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FFilters.vue,src%2Fstore%2Findex.js,src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FFlight.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FFlightList.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FArrivalPoint.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FDeparturePoint.vue

```js
computed: {
    flights() {
      return this.$store.getters.getFlights;
    },
    // filtered computed flights for selectors
    flightsClasses() {
      return this.flights.filter((item, index, objects) => {
        if (index === 0) {
          return item;
        } else if (item.trip_class !== objects[index - 1].trip_class) {
          return item;
        }
      }).sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Could flights be an array-like instead of actual array. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70557050/cannot-map-through-array-of-files-images-react/70557145#70557145) out.

Comment: The stackblitz sandbox doesn't reproduce the issue.  As it is now, it has its own separate issue with the `filterFlights` method where it creates a local variable with the same name as the param, and then tries to use undefined variables `filteredFlightClass` and `filteredChanges`... Please make sure the reproduction actually reproduces the problem in question.  Without that it'll be much harder for others to help.

Comment: It'll probably end up being a problem with `setFilteredFlights` setting `this.state.flights` with data that is not actually an array.  Looking in Filters.vue, you're sending an object to the store method and then setting flights to that data **object**. Some basic debugging should be all thats necessary to figure out the problem.  If you add some console logs surrounding the setting of the `flights` state you should be able to uncover what's happening (or use the wonderful tool [Vue devtools](https://devtools.vuejs.org/) to view a live snapshot of your store's state in the browser)